# Static data(caching) refresh at runtime

Tags: .net, static, runtime, refresh

I am using Static to hold the data for caching. This is used in window services.

My Caching Code is below.

```
public class CacheLoader
```

`{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _cache;
    private static Boolean _loaded = false;
    private static object _lockObject = new object();
    private ILoader _loader;
    public CacheLoader(ILoader loaderObj)
    {
        _loader = loaderObj;
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Load()
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            if (!_loaded)
            {
                _cache = _loader.Load();
                _loaded = true;
            }
        }
        return _cache;
    }
    public static void Clear()
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            _cache = null;
            _loaded = false;
        }
    }
}`

My question is, How can I refresh(reload) this static data at runtime. I don't want to use timer, because cache is refreshed every time the timer expires.

I want the cache to be refreshed when it is needed like, making it refreshed manually without restarting the window service.

I thought of using the file watching concept i.e., a separate thread that watches over a file, if changed cache is refreshed.

Is that correct?

Comment: What triggers are there for a cache refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Provide a WCF endpoint to your service or use any other IPC mechanism for communicating with it from your application (named pipes, for example). Then, you can trigger a refresh easily. Also see the [article](http://arcanecode.com/2007/05/30/windows-services-in-c-sending-commands-to-your-windows-service-part-7/) here showing how to use the OnCustomCommand handler for one-way only communication.